# Empty an array and propogate change through data binding?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer-1.0

This is an almost awkwardly "easy" question, but I couldn't find the answer. :/

In `Polymer 1.0`, how do I clear an array and make sure that the changes propogate to the UI?

I know of the `push`, `pop`, `splice`, `shift`, `unshift` that is mentioned in the [Polymer-documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html). They are supposed to be used like: `this.push("myArray", {})`. But how to clear an array effectively? Looping through the array and calling pop() will trigger the event for each item which isn't ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used to work for me:

this.splice('myarray', 0, this.myarray.length);

bin: http://jsbin.com/rucejo/4/edit?html,output

Comment: Hmm, not sure what I'm doing wrong but that doesn't work. :(

Comment: I now see it did work...kinda. But my array will still contain this item and won't get removed: `[splices: Object]`. Do you have any clues? :o

Comment: It seems that it does work. Not sure what the item i mentioned in comment is though. It is still there, but the array length is now 0. Thanks!

Comment: mmm, can't get what you mean by [splices:Object], but this seems to work:http://jsbin.com/rucejo/4/edit?html,output